# How can I write my own custom disabler?

Tags: pipelines, events, sitecore-api

Sitecore ships with a bunch of disablers, like the `SecurityDisabler` and the `EventsDisabler`, but what if I want to write my own?

I have a bunch of `item:saved` event handlers that run but when I add a new item from a particular snippet of code I want to disable one of my `item:saved` event handlers' logic. If possible, I would like to have a solution that I could use for the same purpose in a custom pipeline processor too. How would I go about this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Sitecore's built in disablers, like the `SecurityDisabler` and the `EventsDisabler` classes, all inherit the Sitecore-provided `Switcher` class. This class is an `IDisposable` that can be used to create disablers for use in both pipeline processors and event handlers, without issue.

The `Switcher` class is easy enough to implement, but I have written a more readable abstract class to serve as a base for disablers that you may find useful:

```cs
    public abstract class Disabler<TSwitchType> : Switcher<DisablerState, TSwitchType>
    {
        public Disabler() : base(DisablerState.Enabled)
        {
        }

        public static bool IsActive => CurrentValue == DisablerState.Enabled;
    }

    public enum DisablerState
    {
        Disabled,
        Enabled
    }
```

Note that the `Switcher` class is used for more than just Sitecore's disablers. It is also used for Sitecore's various `____Switcher` classes, like the `SiteContextSwitcher`, the `LanguageSwitcher`, and more. The class works by reading from and moving objects in the stack, and arguably one of the most under-utilized features of the Sitecore API.

**Example 1: Pipeline Processor Disabler**

I first created the following disabler:

```cs
public sealed class SaveItemLogicDisabler : Disabler<SaveItemLogicDisabler>
{
}
```

I then created my `<saveItem>` pipeline processor and added a check to see if the disabler was active. If so, I skipped executing *that processor*. Note that I made the intentional implementation decision to not abort the pipeline, here, as there are other processors that I may still want to run.

```cs
    public override void Process([NotNull] SaveItemArgs args)
    {
        // this is managed in configuration (runIfAborted=true would have to be set to override the value)
        if (args.Aborted)
        {
            return;
        }

        Assert.IsNotNull(args.Item, "Item is null");
        Assert.IsNotNull(args.FallbackProvider, "FallbackProvider is null");

        args.ProcessorItem = args.Item;
        args.Result = args.FallbackProvider.SaveItem(args.Item);

        // check disabler and decide whether or not to continue execution
        if (SaveItemLogicDisabler.IsActive)
        {
            return;
        }

        // additional processor logic here...
    }
```

**Example 2: Event Handler Disabler**

Let's say that I want to use the same disabler for my `item:saved` events.

I can actually do the exact same check inside of my event handler:

```cs
    private void OnItemSaved([NotNull] object sender, [NotNull] EventArgs args)
    {
        Assert.ArgumentNotNull(sender, nameof(sender));
        Assert.ArgumentNotNull(args, nameof(args));

        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(this.RuleFolderId))
        {
            return;
        }

        // check disabler and decide whether or not to continue execution
        if (SaveItemLogicDisabler.IsActive)
        {
            return;
        }

        // additional handler logic here...
    }
```

Comment: If you can, can you provide an example of implementing a custom disabled to satisfy the use case you provided in the question?

Comment: Sure thing, @PeteNavarra. Give me a moment or two to update.