# Catching the name of an event that triggered another event

Tags: events

I am using Sitecore 9.1.1

The issue is, I have a custom eventhandler for `onPublishEnd` where I set the value of a  certain field (Ex: Field A) by using `BeginEdit()` and `EndEdit()`, which in turn triggers the `onSaving` event.

I also have a custom `onSaving` event where I change the value of another field in the item (Ex: Field B).

What happens is, because `EndEdit()` in my custom `onPublish` triggers the `onSaving` event, my item is changed twice. I need a way for my item to only be changed when `onSaving` is **not triggered from** `onPublish`.

Is there a way to capture the name of the event that triggered another event? Can I check inside the `onSaving` custom event if it was triggered by `onPublish` or not?

Comment: What you're doing, you really shouldn't be doing. You should hook into the uiSaved pipeline rather than relying on events like this. That said; your Context.Site.Name will be `publisher` when publish is running.

Comment: @MarkCassidy Thanks for the reply, I tried using the UiSaved pipeline, but for some reason it doesnt save the changes to the item at all, even though i use BeginEdit and EndEdit, and I tried adding SecurityDisabler as well, the changes dont reflect at all..any idea why?

Comment: Well I know you don't need to use BeginEdit/EndEdit, the item is already in that state. Be mindful you're grabbing the correct item - see this article for an example: https://blog.krusen.dk/hooking-sitecores-save-pipeline/

Comment: @MarkCassidy when I didn't use BeginEdit/EndEdit I would always get an exception that the item is not in editing mode, however i got it eventually working by modifiying the processor configuration, I'm writing an answer now.. thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to my original question could have worked as Mark suggested, by looking at Context.Site.Name during the onSaving event, but then I tried to go with the best practice and use UISaved pipeline, as it triggers only when the Sitecore user "Saves" from within the Sitecore Content editor, so that worked perfectly for my case.

I was trying to change my workflow state field, but for some reason the changes wouldn't reflect in the item after saving, however this is how it finally worked:

I added the following code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using Sitecore.Caching;
using Sitecore.Configuration;
using Sitecore.Data;
using Sitecore.Data.Items;
using Sitecore.Pipelines.Save;

namespace Example.Workflows
{
    public class SaveUIProcessor
    {   
        public virtual void Process(SaveArgs args)
        {
            foreach (SaveArgs.SaveItem saveItem in args.Items)
            {
                var item = Sitecore.Context.ContentDatabase.Items[saveItem.ID, saveItem.Language, saveItem.Version];
                if (item != null)
                {
                    setWorkflowState(item);
                }
            }
        }

        protected virtual void setWorkflowState(Item item)
        {
                using (new Sitecore.SecurityModel.SecurityDisabler())
                {
                    try
                    {
                        item.Editing.BeginEdit();
                        item.Fields["__Workflow"].Value = WorkflowID;
                        item.Fields["__Workflow State"].Value = ReviewStateID;
                        item.Editing.EndEdit(true,false);
                    }
                    catch(Exception ex)
                    {
                        Sitecore.Diagnostics.Log.SingleError("Error in workflow state set on saveui" + ex, ex);
                    }
                }
         }
    }
}
```

I also added the following patch in a .config file for the processor, it ensures that my custom code runs before Sitecore.Pipelines.Save.WorkflowSaveCommand:

```
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
  <sitecore>
    <processors>
      <saveUI>
        <processor mode="on" type="Example.Workflows.SaveUIProcessor, Example.Workflows" patch:before="processor[@type='Sitecore.Pipelines.Save.WorkflowSaveCommand, Sitecore.Kernel']" />
      </saveUI>
    </processors>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

After doing this, the changes reflected successfully.

this answer was also pretty helpful https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/a/923/3547