# AddFromTemplate Pipeline Processor Explanation

Tags: pipelines

I am writing a processor for the `<addFromTemplate>` pipeline.  I noticed the following code in a number of the examples

1. `var item = args.FallbackProvider.AddFromTemplate(args.ItemName, args.TemplateId, args.Destination, args.NewId);`
2. `args.ProcessorItem = args.Result = item;`

What do 1 and 2 do?

Answer (score 2):

When you write an `<addFromTemplate>` pipeline processor, you are actually replacing the default behavior of the `ItemProvider.AddFromTemplate` method. Every `ItemProvider` pipeline sends in the native `ItemProvider` as the `args.FallbackProvider`. As such, when you call the following, what you are actually doing is analogous to `base.AddFromTemplate`, wherein you are calling the native logic within your "overriding" (sort of - this isn't really the right term) method:

```
// analogous to base.AddFromTemplate
var item = args.FallbackProvider.AddFromTemplate(args.ItemName, args.TemplateId, args.Destination, args.NewId);
```

Since you are writing a processor, the only way to return a result is by setting a property on your Pipeline arguments. As such, we "return" (sort of - again, this isn't really the right term) a result by setting the `args.Result` property. Additionally, if there are any other processors then they should use the "result" of this processor instead of the item this processor started with as the `args.ProcessorItem`:

```
args.ProcessorItem =    // any other processors should use this item
    args.Result = item; // this is the result
```

#### More Information:

- [Example of how to write an `<addFromTemplate>` pipeline processor](http://zacharykniebel.com/blog/sitecore/2016/march/30/using-sitecores-new-addfromtemplate-item-provider-pipeline)
- [This post on writing custom disablers shows the same pattern used for the `<saveItem>` item provider pipeline](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/a/529/423)
- [This post shows how the `<addFromTemplate>` pipeline can be used to write code that adds support for Branch Presets](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/a/2927/423)